# Line breaking with fancyvrb and fvextra doesn't work when injecting commands in Verbatim environment

Tags: line-breaking, latex3, fancyvrb, fvextra

Using `fancyvrb` and `fvextra`, it's possible to get verbatim environments to breaklines at any location to accomodate the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\begin{document}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines, breakanywhere}

\begin{MyVerbatim}
def f(x):
    s = "908df0sdfdsfsd78g89f7g98fd7gh98fdhfd7h98df7h98dfh99h8dfa897hf9d7h98fd7hf98dh"
    return x
\end{MyVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I add `commandchars` and inject a command within the verbatim environment, the line breaking algorithm of `fvextra` is somehow overriden.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Tok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.3, 0.4, 0.2}{#1}}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{MyOtherVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{breaklines, breakanywhere, commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{MyOtherVerbatim}
def f(x):
    s = \Tok{"908df0sdfdsfsd78g89f7g98fd7gh98fdhfd7h98df7h98dfh99h8dfa897hf9d7h98fd7hf98dh"}
    return x
\end{MyOtherVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does this occur? How can I still get line breaking even if I'm injecting custom commands like that?